# Python nested for loops

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, nested

```
car_list=[['BMW',4,False,200],['Mercedes',3,False,250],['Renault',2,False,150],['Audi',3,False,180]] #car list

new_list=[] 
def add_new_car(horsepower,brand,car_list):
    for lists in car_list:
        for i in lists:
            if brand==i :
                lists[1]=lists[1]+1
                print(car_list)

            else: #from there i dont want to execute program when brand is mercedes. if brand is different from list i want to execute . but program executes.:$$
                if brand != i:
                    new_list.append(brand)
                    new_list.append(1)
                    new_list.append(True)
                    new_list.append(horsepower)
                    car_list.append(new_list)
                    print(car_list)
                    break
        break

brand='Mercedes' #when brand is mercedes program executes else if part and creates new list and add this lst to car list. but i cant add it to existed mercedes list as> mercedes,3,false,250 
horsepower=170

add_new_car(horsepower,brand,car_list)
```

My code is not working as I want it to. I can't do the thing when the brand is mercedes it executes the else if part and creates new list.. but i want to add it to existing mercedes list..  and new list will be

```
[['BMW',4,False,200],['Mercedes',4,False,250],['Renault',2,False,150],['Audi',3,False,180]]
```

not

```
[['BMW', 4, False, 200], ['Mercedes', 3, False, 250], ['Renault', 2, False, 150], ['Audi', 3, False, 180], ['Mercedes', 1, True, 170]]
```

what can i do for it?

Comment: It's not clear what you want the output to be. How did the program reach to that output you posted? Why `BMW` value changed to `3`? Please post the final output required for that code. Also, is brand always going to be `Mercedes`? What happens when I pass `'BMW'`?

Comment: sorry i was mistaken.. bmw list is the same as initial.. the final output of this code 
[['BMW', 4, False, 200], ['Mercedes', 3, False, 250], ['Renault', 2, False, 150], ['Audi', 3, False, 180], ['Opel', 1, True, 170]] when the brand is Opel.. 
but when the brand is mercedes it is [['BMW', 4, False, 200], ['Mercedes', 3, False, 250], ['Renault', 2, False, 150], ['Audi', 3, False, 180], ['Mercedes', 1, True, 170]].. however it must be [['BMW',4,False,200],['Mercedes',4,False,250],['Renault',2,False,150],['Audi',3,False,180]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for you İlayda. You do not need to add inner for loop and putting else after for loop guarantees to add new item if there is no match.

```
car_list = [['BMW', 4, False, 200], ['Mercedes', 3, False, 250], ['Renault', 2, False, 150], ['Audi', 3, False, 180]]

def add_new_car(horsepower, brand, car_list):
    for lists in car_list:
        if lists[0] == brand:
            lists[1] += 1
            break
    else:
        new_list = []
        new_list.append(brand)
        new_list.append(1)
        new_list.append(True)
        new_list.append(horsepower)
        car_list.append(new_list)

brand = 'Mercedes'
horsepower = 170

add_new_car(horsepower, brand, car_list)
print car_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate over the inner list. That loop is the reason, you're going to `else if` part for every input. Just check the `brand` value with `lists[0]` index value.

I guess the following function should be enough. To add the `brand` to the list if it isn't already there, you can use `else` part of `for` loop, which is executed when the loop completes without `break`.

```
def add_new_car(horsepower,brand,car_list):
    for lists in car_list:
        if lists[0] == brand:
            lists[1] = lists[1]+1
            break
    else:
        cart_list.append([brand, 1, True, horsepower])
```

Comment: Oh yeah..That's really make sense.. Thank you Rohit:)